# convert date into XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a date(string) value in an XML file in this format:

```
<UserValue title="fnd0EndDate" value="2017-01-18T09:18:19Z" />
```

I want to use XSL transformation to convert the string/date into this format:

```
01JAN2017:09:18:19
```

How can I do that in my XSL transform?

Comment: is it xslt version 1 or 2?

Comment: xslt version 1...

Answer (score 2):

With **XSLT 2.0 (or 3)** it can be as simple as evaluating the dateTime value as an `xs:dateTime` and using [`format-dateTime()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-format-dateTime) with the desired picture:

```
format-dateTime(xs:dateTime(UserValue/@value), '[M01][MN,*-3][Y]:[H01]:[m01]:[s01]')
```

However, with **XSLT 1.0**, you don't have the dateTime methods available and are relegated to string parsing:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:variable name="MONTHS">
    <month>JAN</month>
    <month>FEB</month>
    <month>MAR</month>
    <month>APR</month>
    <month>MAY</month>
    <month>JUN</month>
    <month>JUL</month>
    <month>AUG</month>
    <month>SEP</month>
    <month>OCT</month>
    <month>NOV</month>
    <month>DEC</month>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="val" select="//UserValue/@value"/>
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring($val, 6, 2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="month-name" select="document('')/*/*/month[position() = number($month)]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring($val, 1, 4)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="time" select="substring($val, 12, 8)"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="concat($month, $month-name, $year, ':', $time)"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```